# Data structure with index and two values in java

Tags: java, android, data-structures, key-value

I have some data that I would like to organise, but I've found that a key-value data structure doesn't fit my requirements.

I have some data like this:

```
1    |  new CustomObject[] {...}
1    |  etc...
5    |  
8    |  
19   |
```

Currently, I am putting the first column into a key, and the second into a value.

The issue I'm having is that when I'm putting new values into the key-value data structure, sometimes the values from one key get overriden since there are multiple values with the same key.

Ideally, the data structure I am looking for would have methods such as `keyAt(int index)`.

**Does anyone know what sort of data structure could fit my requirements?**

Since I am developing for Android, I have already looked at the documentation of Android's data structures like [`SparseArray<E>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) and [`ArrayMap<K, V>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html), however they are both key-value structures meaning that my key would be overriden when putting new values.

Comment: What it seems to me is that you want to save two values (that you're calling key and value) into a value, because if the key isn't unique, it's not really a "key".

But isn't that just  a simple List<Tuple<K, V>> ?

Comment: Why don't you join the values with the same key? Ex: "1 -> [2,3], 1 -> [4]" --> "1 -> [2,3,4]" ?

Comment: @Salem I could do that but I have a feeling it will unnecessarily complicate my code, since I already have an array as my value.

Comment: @PedroDavid You know, I didn't think of that! I'll probably use your suggestion unless someone can come up with something better.

Comment: Just as a side note, it's easy to create a Tuple<T, K> but one thing that I find is that it's "too generic", what will you call the getters? I usually call getFirst() and getSecond(), but then what is first and what is second? Depending on the complexity of your project a specific class without generics might be clearer.

Comment: Just make your value a list and use HashMap maybe like Map<K,ArrayList<V>>

Comment: @PedroDavid Is there even a tuple in java?

Comment: Actually, I released I can use [`Pair`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) like a tuple, since I am developing for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [*Pedro*'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621713/data-structure-with-index-and-two-values-in-java?noredirect=1#comment64629266_38621713), I was able to find a solution for my particular use case.

Since I am using Android, I used the [`Pair<F, S>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html) class (also available via the v4 Support Library) and a `List<E>` to help me achieve what I wanted.

I used:

```
List<Pair<Integer, CustomObject>>
```

Answer (score 1):

- From my understanding, what you really want is something like an
  in-order array that has two values per index. What you could do based
  off of my understanding is have two parallel `ArrayList`s where one is
  the 'key' list and the other holds the values associated with the
  keys. You just have to make sure that when you add something to one,
  you also update the other. Another thing you could do is create a
  class where each instance of the class holds both the 'key' and its
  value.

  - The problem with these approaches is that you won't keep the ability
    to pull by key, but rather you'd have to pull by index and then check
    the key and value.
- Another option is to have a `HashMap<Key, List<value>>`, so that each key has a list of the values associated with it.

  - The problem with this approach is that you'd either have to check for existence of a key then append to the existing list when adding a new element.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Key {
  public int hashCode() {
  /*terurn something*/
 }
}

Map<Key,ArrayList<V>>
```

What doesn't fit your requirements in this ?

Comment: It seems your Key class can simply be the Integer class. No need to define a separate Key class!

Comment: Well, in general, if you want to save something in hashtable it must be hashable

Comment: Yes, the primitive int is obviously not 'hashable', but Integer certainly is.

Comment: I assume the hashcode of Integer is simply the integer value itself but not 100% sure.

Comment: Also, rather use List (an interface) as opposed to ArrayList (an implementation). I agree with your general idea though.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode() I don't understand your "int vs integer" concept anyway. 
but agree with List. List is general, you tell me to produce more general examples, well my example with hashcode is general.

Comment: What I am saying is that the Integer class already has a hashCode method. No need to create a new class called Key. Replace Key with Integer. Integer is a perfectly valid key class for Map.

Comment: I know that but no one said that keys  values are integers. It can be any data structure.(at least it's unclear from question ) this is why i wanted general example

Comment: Yes. Ok, I see what you mean by general example. From the OP's question it certainly looks like he wants Integer keys though. I also thought your Key class was supposed to be basically complete.  Anyway, I get your point. :)